# Initial counter value not displaying on ChangeDetectionPush strategy

Tags: javascript, angular

I am writing a simple `counter`. It has `start,stop, toggle` functionality in `parent (app`) and displaying changed value in `child (counter) component` using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`.

Issue I am facing is not able to display `initial counter value` in child component on load.

Below are screenshot and code.

[image]

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
template: `<h1>Change Detection</h1>

<button (click)="start()">Start</button>
<button (click)="stop()">Stop</button>
<button (click)="toggleCD()">Toggle CD</button>
<hr>
<counter [data]="data$" [notifier]="notifier$"></counter>`,
})
export class AppComponent {

_counter = 0;
_interval;
_cdEnabled = false;
data$ = new BehaviorSubject({counter: 0});
notifier$ = new BehaviorSubject(false);

start() {
 if (!this._interval) {
    this._interval = setInterval((() => {
        this.data$.next({counter: ++this._counter});
    }), 10);
 }
}

stop() {
 clearInterval(this._interval);
 this._interval = null;
}
toggleCD(){
  this._cdEnabled = !this._cdEnabled;
  this.notifier$.next(this._cdEnabled);
 }
}
```

**counter.component.ts**

```
import {Component, Input, ChangeDetectionStrategy, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/index';

 @Component({
  selector: 'counter',
  template: `Items: {{_data.counter}}`,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class CounterComponent implements OnInit {

@Input() data: Observable<any>;
@Input() notifier: Observable<boolean>;
_data: any;

constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.data.subscribe((value) => {
  /**
  Below this._data.counter is showing 0 in console.log but
  not in template
  **/
  this._data = value;
  this.cd.markForCheck();
});

this.cd.detach();
this.notifier.subscribe((value) => {
  if (value) {
       this.cd.reattach();
    } else {
      this.cd.detach();
    }
  });
 }
}
```

I'm using `Angular 6.1.0`

Answer (score 1):

your AppComponent `data$` is a BehaviorSubject, which you have given an initial value.  your CounterComponent `data` expects an Observable, which you subscribe to.  The defaulted BehaviorSubject does not fire until it changes.  to get the value you have to query it upon load:

```js
@Input() data: BehaviorSubject<any>;

ngOnInit() {
  this._data = this.data.value; // get the initial value from the subject
  this.data.subscribe((value) => {
    this._data = value;
    this.cd.markForCheck();
  }
);
```

should do the trick.

Comment: It's not working. actually I was getting initial value printed in console.log. pls see my edit